Current code is not adding the 4 columns into multiple Workbooks as needed
I am new to VBA coding, but I have repetitive tasks at work that are tedious and I would like to automate. One such tasks is taking ~60 files one for each county in my area and adding an instruction page (which I have done successfully with vba) then adding 4 columns A2:F2 with highlighted headers from my source workbook with the VBA code and inserting this range of 4 columns into each of the 60 workbooks on the second tab.
Sub CopyDataToMultipleWorkbooks()
    Dim sourceWB As Workbook
    Dim sourceWS As Worksheet
    Dim destFolder As String
    Dim destFilename As String
    Dim destWB As Workbook
    Dim destWS As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowSource As Long
    Dim lastRowDest As Long
    Dim i As Long
    
    ' Set the source workbook and worksheet
    Set sourceWB = ThisWorkbook
    Set sourceWS = sourceWB.Sheets(2)
    
    ' Set the destination folder path
    destFolder = "K:\2024 Cycle\Data Management"
    
    ' Find the last row of data in the source worksheet
    lastRowSource = sourceWS.Cells(sourceWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    ' Loop through each file in the destination folder
    destFilename = Dir(destFolder & "*.xlsx")
    Do While destFilename <> ""
        ' Open the destination workbook
        Set destWB = Workbooks.Open(destFolder & destFilename)
        
        ' Set the destination worksheet
        Set destWS = destWB.Sheets(2)
        
        ' Find the last row of data in the destination worksheet
        lastRowDest = destWS.Cells(destWS.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
        ' Copy data from source worksheet to destination worksheet
        sourceWS.Range("A2:F2" & lastRowSource).Copy destWS.Range("A" & lastRowDest + 1)
        
        ' Close and save the destination workbook
        destWB.Close SaveChanges:=True
        
        ' Get the next filename in the folder
        destFilename = Dir
    Loop
    

    MsgBox "Data has been copied to all destination workbooks in the folder.", vbInformation
End Sub

Results: I get no errors, it looks like it is going through the looping with the opening and closing of the files,  I get the task finished message, but when I open up each of the 60 files it as if nothing was added or saved.

I don't see anything obviously wrong. I would probably step through my code if this was me - main thing is making sure the workbook and worksheet references are correct, and of course the copying is happening (and if not ... well, what is happening). Debugging tips: programming-excel-vba-debugging
